# How to add a spinner in a toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add spinner and edittext field for search in app bar but I am getting something like this image below:

[image]

What I want is like this image below:

[image]

My menu item is shifted below with an search bar I want to make it look like as in 2nd image.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/chooseLocation"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:hint="Search here"
            android:textColorHint="#9e9e9e"
            android:textColor="#000"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
            android:background="@drawable/search_edit_text"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_check"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_check"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Someone please let me know how can I achieve desired layout.Any help would be appreciated

**THANKS**

Comment: Keep the spinner in the toolbar and place the edittext below the toolbar.

Comment: Its not working edit text is now out of toolbar and its background is white now.

Comment: Well wrap it in a layout or something and add color..

Comment: Thanks, bro got it.